# Does the eigenvalue that the Power Method converges to have to be "strictly" dominant?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra

In almost all the text I can find on the Power method, the authors say something to this effect:

> If we assume A has an eigenvalue that is strictly greater in magnitude than its other eigenvalues and the starting vector b_0 has a nonzero component in the direction of an eigenvector associated with the dominant eigenvalue, then a subsequence (b_k) converges to an eigenvector associated with the dominant eigenvalue.
> Without the two assumptions above, the sequence (b_k) does not necessarily converge.

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration#The_method)

I can intuitively understand the second condition. But can someone explain to me intuitively (or with an example) why an $n \times n$ matrix with, say, 2 (or 3 or maybe even n-1) equal eigenvalues which are greater than the remaining n-2(or n-3... or 1) eigenvalues could not converge?

What I understand is, if we have a single strictly dominant eigenvalue, then the initial guess $b_0$ (which has a component in the direction of the corresponding eigenvector) is bound to converge after some time to the eigenvector.

What I don't understand is, however, why this logic cannot be extended to more than 1 and written this way: "if we have dominant eigenvalue(s), then the initial guess $b_0$ (which has a component in the eigenspace corresponding to the dominant eigenvalue) is bound to converge after some time to a vector in the eigenspace." (Assuming of course that the matrix is diagonalisable which is a requirement for all cases anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is “yes”: take, for example, the basic two-circulant matrix
$$
C= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},$$
which has two dominant eigenvalues ($\pm 1$).

If $$x =
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix},$$
then
$$Cx =
\begin{bmatrix}
x_2 \\
x_1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and

$$C^2x =
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Thus, convergence fails in general.

Comment: Although this is true, in order to address the OP's question you would need an example with $|\lambda_1|=|\lambda_2| > |\lambda_3|$.